# Muestra un undefined en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto en HTML con funciones en Javascript, para esto no sé mucho de Javascript; estoy trabajando en el login de la página, y me surge una incidencia al querer traer los datos de las cajas de texto para almacenarlas en unas variables en Javascript, esto es lo que llevo

```html
    <body>
    <div class="login-container">
        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/295/295128.png" alt="Login">
        <p>Login</p>
        <div class="fields">
            <div class="data">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input type="username" id="email" placeholder="Usuario">
            </div>
            <div class="data">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Contrasena">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="registrar()" class="btn-login">Login</button>
    </div>


    <!---<script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function registrar(){
        var emai = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;

        console.log(this.emai);
        console.log(this.pass);
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

y al correrlo y abrir la consola del navegador me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: Los undefined se supone que tiene que dar los datos de las cajas de texto]

Lo pruebo tanto directamente en el código HTML y por separado en un archivo independiente de  .js y en los dos muestra el mismo resultado.

Comment: la advertencia (el amarillo) te dice que tiene mal escrito `device-width`.  al momento de hacer los console.log, ya pusiste datos en los componentes? igual no sé si tendrá que ver algo entre la comilla simple (') y la doble (") podrías intentar cone eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentarios, efectivamente tenias razón, eran cuestiones de comillas, las cambien por dobles y así si tomo los datos y se mostraron en consola y también tenias razón la advertencia en amarillo fue por un error de sintaxis, corregí ambos detalles y funciono correcto.

Comment: Otra pregunta, que determina que se ocupen en este caso o en otros las comillas simples o dobles o cuando se tendrían que colocar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en referencia a tu problema verifique tu código, para poder ver el contenido de cada input simplemente quita el "this", ya con eso deberías poder obtener el valor correcto.

Estas obteniendo como resultado "undefined" ya que al hacer las declaraciones "var emai" y "var pass" logras que estas solo existan en el ámbito de tu función "registrar", y, cuando haces uso de "this", (este hace referencia al objeto global, osea window), y ahí tus variables no existen.

Si hubieras declarado tus variables sin el sufijo "var" las mismas harian referencia al objeto global (cuando no usas el modo estricto) y en ese caso obtendrias por consola el resultado esperado.

El uso de "this" en Javascript es mucho mas amplio que lo que te comento, por eso te dejo un link donde podrás encontrar una pequeña explicación para el uso de "this".

Saludos.

[Aprender a utilizar this](https://wmedia.es/aprender-usar-this-javascript/#:%7E:text=this%20es%20una%20referencia%20que,en%20s%C3%AD%20a%20la%20funci%C3%B3n.)

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente la información más relevante del enlace que proporcionas. Recuerda que los enlaces pueden romperse, perdiéndose así parte esencial de la respuesta.